# Rails single table inheritance with reference different columns in different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, single-table-inheritance

How can I have 2 different references columns in 2 models which inherit from a common class using single table inheritance?

I have found this [Single Table Inheritance (STI) column associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160285/single-table-inheritance-sti-column-associations) answer but as it is 10 years ago is there a better solution now in rails?

Problem example:
I want something like
Consider classes (Animal has type to identify the Lion/Human)

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :classA
end

class Lion < Animal
    belongs_to :two_legged
end

class Human < Animal
    belongs_to :four_legged
end
```

So finally I want Lion to belong to `classA` and `two_legged`; Human to belong to `classA` and `four_legged`

Is there any other better solution than to define all three belongs_to in Animal and making unrelated column nil in Lion & Human ??

Comment: All are models right?(Animal, Lion, Human)

Comment: This sounds a bit like you want a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) @Rahul.

Comment: All are models - Animal, Lion, Human, two_legged, four_legged

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official [doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :classA
    has_many :lions
    has_many :humans
end

class Lion < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :animal
end

class Human < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :animal
end
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: two_leg and four_leg is may not be a table. may be it type of animal

Comment: This solution doesn't use single table inheritance and two_legged and four legged are also models